# Deploying web apps that use firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Assuming that I used Firebase services on my web and I want to deploy the web app on a hosting site, do I have to do deploy it in Firebase hosting or any hosting site will do?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firebase, then it already has a free hosting domain. So you can directly deploy it on Firebase. [Here's](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying) a guide for you. If you want, you can also use a [custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) and it's free on Firebase now.

Comment: Not necessary. You'll just have to buy a domain, maybe at GoDaddy, then use it in Firebase. Here's the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain

Answer (score 1):

Web apps that use Firebase features (such as the Realtime Database, Storage, Authentication or any of the others) *can* be deployed any hosting service. Using Firebase Hosting is not required.

Comment: is there any configuration or things i have to do to deploy it on any hosting site?

Comment: Not that I know of. If you're having problems, post what you've done and what problem you're having.